# Admin User model

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

My admin user model does not update new record when I register using UserCreationForm.

[Access the github code](https://github.com/Abunawest2/My-blog-site)

in the views I have imported Usercreationform has shown below and I did all the views coding. I do not know where I went wrong. I also rendered the form correctly into the template. But the annoying part comes after filling the form. It doesn't update in the admin panel once I accessed it

```
// View file:

from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', context)

// Template file:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="" method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="register">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you exactly mean by **My admin user model does not update new record when I register using UserCreationForm**?

Comment: Hello! My English is kinder poor. I created a form to register new users using the Django usercreationform however the users don't get registered when I ever I register.

Comment: You mean from your frontend form?

Comment: No, from my admin panel after filling out the form in the front end.

Comment: I was expecting to see a new user added to the User model after filling out the form

Comment: Yes I understand, I mean user is not registering when you fill the form from frontend, but it is registering when you do it with admin panel, is that right?

Comment: Ya, when I do it in the admin panel it is registering but from the front end is where it doesn't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excerpt from the docs:

> You should always return an [`HttpResponseRedirect`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) after successfully dealing with POST data. This tip isn’t specific to Django; it’s good web development practice in general.

So try the following view:

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def home(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect("success_page")
        else:
            return redirect("some_error_page")
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', {'form':form})

def success(request):
    return render(request, 'main/success.html')
```

Your urls.py should be:

```py
urlpatterns=[
    path('', v.home, name='home')
    path('success/', v.success, name='success_page')
]
```

success.html

```html
<body>
    <h1> The form has been successfully submitted. </h1>
    
    <a href="{% url 'home' %}"> Go to homepage </a>
</body>
```

The same URL pattern and HTML page, you can make for displaying error if the form is not valid.

You can also remove empty `action` attribute as Django by default takes current page route so the template should be like:

```html
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <input type="submit" value="register">
</form>
```